# How to avoid new cookies or overwriting existing cookies in a session?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

I am sorry to say this.. I am not very familiar to cookies and its uses.

My application stores some data in session which persists till end of session.
I have the option to search an employee and edit some of his details in a form.

This functionality works fine in my local tomcat server.
While deploying it in main server, the search result is displayed in a page with new JsessionId and hence my object is not available after editing the options in new page.

I dont see anywhere new cookie is getting created. Could anyone identify the problem ?

(On vary rare cases - once in a 50 clicks, it works fine by taking the same sessionId)

Thanks a lot,
Abbin

Comment: Wait are you setting JAVASCRIPT or PHP session?

Comment: It is a very old application which was working in Spring 2.5.6.

Comment: I updated the spring version alone to 3.0.5 for using spring security. I think session is maintained by spring. But don't know if multiple sessions are getting creaded..

Comment: Provide your code if you want someone to help you. Anyways it SHOULD NOT EVER work, even on rare cases, because the ID generated has to be unique. Try checking cookies on your website. (Easiest way to do that is to enter `javascript:alert(document.cookie);` to your browser's URL adress, while you are on your page.

Comment: I made a temporary fix by gpassing required values in url parameter. I know it is dirty. But it works. As of now.